# Properties file: Use key as variable

Tags: java

I want to use a key defined in properties file as a variable like this:

```
key1= value1
key2= value2
key3= key1
```

I tried:

```
key3= {key1}
```

or

```
key3= ${key1}
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 22):

Java's built-in Properties class doesn't do what you're looking for.

But there are third-party libraries out there that do.  [Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) is one that I have used with some success.  The [`PropertiesConfiguration`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/PropertiesConfiguration.html) class does exactly what you're looking for.

So you might have a file named `my.properties` that looks like this:

```bash
key1=value1
key2=Something and ${key1}
```

Code that uses this file might look like this:

```java
CompositeConfiguration config = new CompositeConfiguration();
config.addConfiguration(new SystemConfiguration());
config.addConfiguration(new PropertiesConfiguration("my.properties"));

String myValue = config.getString("key2");
```

`myValue` will be `"Something and value1"`.

Answer (score 0):

When you define the value of a key in properties file, it will be parsed as literal value. So when you define `key3= ${key1}`, key3 will have value of "${key1}".

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)

I agree with csd, the plain configuration file may not be your choice. I prefer using Apache Ant ( http://ant.apache.org/ ), where you can do something like this:

```
<property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
<property name="conf.dir" value="conf" />
```

Then later when you want to use key 'src.dir', just call it something like this:

```
<dirset dir="${src.dir}"/>
```

Another good thing about using Apache Ant is you also can load the .properties file into Ant build file. Just import it like this:

```
<loadproperties srcFile="file.properties"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

.xmlEven better: use the latest Maven.
You can do some neat stuff with maven. In this case you can make an .properties file with this  lines in it:

```
key1 = ${src1.dir}
key2 = ${src1.dir}/${filename}
key3 = ${project.basedir}
```

in the maven's pom.xml file (placed in the root of your project) you should do something like this:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>just-path-to-the-properties-file-without-it</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>file-name-to-be-filtered</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>

...

<properties>
    <src1.dir>/home/root</src1.dir>
    <filename>some-file-name</filename>
</properties>
```

That way you would have keys values changed in build time, which means that after compiling you will have this values inside your properties file:

```
key1 = /home/root
key2 = /home/root/some-file-name
key3 = the-path-to-your-project
```

compile with this line when you are in the same dir as pom.xml file:
mvn clean install -DskipTests