# Resolve Username In Java Properties File for Usage Tracker

Tags: java, properties-file

I am trying to use the Java Usage Tracker to audit Java usage.  See the following information: https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/usage-tracker/overview/

One of the properties in the properties file specifies where the log is to be saved (the user's home location):

```
# Settings for logging to a file:
# Use forward slashes (/) because backslash is an escape character in a
# properties file.
com.oracle.usagetracker.logToFile = ${user.home}/.java_usagetracker
```

This creates the file: C:\Users\CURRENTUSER\.java_usagetracker correctly.

How can I prepend the current user's logon name and/or hostname to the file?

I've tried:

```
com.oracle.usagetracker.logToFile = ${user.home}/${user.name}.java_usagetracker
```

and a number of other variations but cannot roll the dice correctly.  It appears user.name is a valid property (see here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

FYI: I am attempting to put the log file on a network location where the user's name won't be in the path, which is why I need the username in the file name.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/usage-tracker/overview/toc.htm#A132173581) you'll see that they only specify that ${user.home} will be expanded. No other properties are mentioned as being allowed:

> You can specify ${user.home} in the path name. The property will expand to the user's home directory. For example (ignore line break):
>
> > com.oracle.usagetracker.logToFile = ${user.home}/.java_usagetracker

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are trying to replace built-in environment variable values in the properties file. What you are forgetting is that the Java Properties file is not compiled similar to the '.java' files. Such properties files have to be read via the [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) library.

A similar query has been answered here:
[Properties file : Use key as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228218/properties-file-use-key-as-variable)

Comment: So the ${user.home} is defined elsewhere and resolves but ${user.name} apparently isn't?  Sorry, I am Java agnostic.