# Can I use System Properties in flume configuration

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I have following flume config for a flume sink

```
# Describe the sink
a1.sinks.k1.type = file_roll
a1.sinks.k1.sink.directory = ~/flume_file_sink
a1.sinks.k1.rollInterval = 0
```

I want to make `sink.directory`, `channels.c1.capacity`, `channels.c1.capacity` make configurable (let's say using system properties). It is possible to do so.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it is not possible.

The documentation [says](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#setting-up-an-agent):

*Flume agent configuration is stored in a local configuration file. This is a text file that follows the Java properties file format.*

If not only the format has been mimicked but the behaviour as well, then you wont be able to do variable sustitution within Flume's configuration file (see [Properties file : Use key as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228218/properties-file-use-key-as-variable)).

Answer (score 0):

Most similar to what you want to do, although not as effective is the Exec Source

https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#exec-source

You can execute a unix commands like tail -F /var/log/secure

I hope to help you