# use property in .properties file from other .properties file in java

Tags: java

there is a value in a.properties file, I want use it in `b.properties`, for example in `a.properties` I set a variable `path = "some path"`, how can I use it in `b.properties`,the destination is in b.properties there is a variable `another_path = path/....`  how can I make it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Properties file : Use key as variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228218/properties-file-use-key-as-variable)

Comment: more detail plz, tkx

Comment: As i understand , use simple Java code, get first property from a.properties and get another properties from b.properties file make path at java side. OR YOU WANT TO UPDATE PROPERTIE FILE .

Comment: [Your question is answered here - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412132/can-i-reference-another-property-in-a-properties-file-use-property) As per the answer there, You could use the variable interpretation link. [Apache's Variable Interpolation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_basicfeatures.html#Variable_Interpolation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I reference another property in a properties file (use ${property})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412132/can-i-reference-another-property-in-a-properties-file-use-property)