# Use of variables in .properties files Java

Tags: java, properties-file

So I am working in some web stuff in java and I was wondering if you could use a property as a variable in another property:

```
name = Sam
message = Hello ${name}
```

Something like that

Comment: Not natively, https://stackoverflow.com/a/11228311/221543

Answer (score 1):

If you use spring boot you will get this behaviour out of the box. You may want to use yaml though for your configruation.